# DDS reconstruction filter after amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, filter, noise, dds

I need a clean sine wave from 10 kHz to 2 MHz as an excitation source for an eddy current probe. The sine wave will be generated by an AD9833 DDS with a clock frequency of 25 MHz. As a reconstruction filter I plan to use a 4th order active lowpass (LT1568) with a cut-off frequency of about 3 MHz. The sine wave has an amplitude of about 300 mV and needs to be amplfied by a factor of 15 (LM7323 non-inverting amplifier). Right before the eddy current probe there will be an extra buffer.

In terms of noise the simulation shows better performance when the signal is first amplified and then filtered, which makes sense. Are there any disadvantages of placing the amplifier before the reconstruction filter?

Comment: is noise the best thing to be worried about? I've often optimised for the wrong thing. Would output impedance be a better criterion?

Comment: @Neil_UK I get what you mean, but in this case the goal really is to optimize the signal chain for lowest noise. Of course not if it has any major disadvantages... How do you think output impedance could be a problem in this case? The dds has a current output which internally is converted to a voltage with a 200 Ohm load resistor. Woudn't it be even better to start the signal chain with a high input impedance from the non-inverting amplifier? This amplifier has low output impedance and is followed by the filter. Does the output impedance of the filter really matter that much if it is buffered?

Comment: If you have an extra buffer before the probe, and are using an active filter, then you're not really serious about noise, I'd missed the bit about the extra buffer, which will be giving your probe a low drive impedance. Perhaps it would be better if you illustrate the whole signal chain, from DDS to probe, and write down your noise specification at the probe in suitable units, then you would get meaningful answers.